# Android RecyclerView Inertia

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've updated my RecyclerView version to 26.0.1 and I have pagination implemented with RecyclerView, so when I reach bottom of the list I see ProgressBar and load more data to display, then notify inserted indexes

So with new 26.0.1 RecyclerView version there's inertia saved from scrolling. So when I swipe down fast and reach bottom I see ProgressBar, but after new data inserted RecyclerView keeps scrolling down

I know that's it inertia because if I swipe slowly, it doesn't scroll down after new data being inserted

Question: how to disable this inertia swiping?

P.S. My RecyclerView is inside NestedScrollView

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @uguboz do you need a code? It's RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView with nestedScrolling disabled for RecyclerView. On 25.* version of RecyclerView there's no inertia. I'll try to create a sample app with it to see if it behaves the same

Comment: I dont know what is the exlected behaviour in this situ. But u can stop scrolling on new data load maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late response, but I faced with the same issue.
I had a NestedScrollView containing multiple items including RecyclerView.
I noticed that when LOADING state is shown, everything scrolls without any inertia, but once I make recyclerView visible, inertia appears. That code helped me:

```
recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```

It helped for androidX RecylerView widget.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, a `RecyclerView` with infinite scrolling on API 26. Solved it by just adding this code to the overriden `onScrolled` event I was already using to load subsequent pages of data. I placed it after the `super.onScrolled()` call and before my infinite page loading trigger.

```
if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
    recyclerView.stopScroll();
}
```

This detects whether the `RecyclerView` can no longer scroll downwards (1 for down, -1 for up), and uses the built-in method to halt scrolling.

Comment: Closest thing for a fix. Not perfect, since this scoll event `onScrolled` is somehow reported tiny bit later when the scrolling physically has already happened, so the parent view would still scroll for a small amount before stopping, but I can live with this - better than nothing. Thanks!